# iPhone: View that is a Property Fails to Appear after Adding a @synthesize Directive for the Property

Tags: objective-c, iphone, properties, uiviewcontroller, xib

I have a mainwindow.xib which has a tabbar controller. The first tab bar has a view, that loads from "View1.xib". In my View1.xib, I drag the UI element on it. It has this in .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class View1Controller;


@interface View1Controller : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIView *view;
    IBOutlet UIButton *startButton;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) UIView *view;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIButton *startButton;


-(IBAction)startClock:(id)sender;

@end
```

In .m file, I do nothing. It will behave normally. I can see the view and its button. But after I add :

```
@synthesize view, startButton;
```

When I load the application, it shows a blank view with no button but produces no errors. What is happening?

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is that `UIViewController` already has a `view` property. When you redefine it in the your `UIViewController` subclass you overwrite that view property. Frankly, I'm surprised it even compiles.

To fix:

(1) First, ask yourself if you need another view property beside the inherited one at all. If  you need just one view for the controller, just used the inherited property.

(2) If you do need a referece to second view, name it like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
//@class View1Controller; <-- don't forward declare a class in its own header


@interface View1Controller : UIViewController {
    // IBOutlet UIView *view; <-- this is inherited from UIViewController
    IBOutlet UIView *myView;
    IBOutlet UIButton *startButton;
}
//@property (retain, nonatomic) UIView *view; <-- this is inherited from UIViewController
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIView *myView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIButton *startButton;


-(IBAction)startClock:(id)sender;

@end
```

then in the implementation:

```
//@synthesize view; <-- this is inherited from UIViewController
@synthesize myView, startButton;
```

Comment: +1, this happened to me... Took a lot of trial and error to find, should have consulted Stack Overflow first!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you declared your `view` and `startButton` variables as IBOutlets.  This means that Interface Builder is binding these variables directly from the XIB file.

The properties you defined aren't IBOutlets though.  When you synthesize them, you overwrite the getters/setters and Interface Builder cannot bind to them anymore.

To fix your problem, remove the IBOutlet specifier from your member variables and change your property declarations to the following:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *startButton;
```

Comment: I agree, the  synthesize will create a getter and setter method for your property but without the IBOutlet it will not relate to the XIB and because you are overriding the view you get a blank. It is my opinion though that putting the IBOutlet will work even if you do not touch the UIViewController {UIViewController
    IBOutlet UIView *myView;
    IBOutlet UIButton *startButton;
}